# Differential Equation with Euler multiplier

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following D.E.

$$xy'+(lnx)y =lnx$$

First I need to bring it to the form $y'+a(x)y=b(x)$, so it becomes:
$$y'+\frac{lnx}{x}y=\frac{lnx}{x} $$

After this, I need to calculate the $\int a(x)dx$ which will give me:
$$\int{\frac{lnx}{x}dx} = \frac{(lnx)^2}{2} +c$$

So the Euler multiplier is $e^\frac{(lnx)^2}{2}$. Now I multiply my equation with this, at each side and get on the left side the product rule:

$$(ye^\frac{(lnx)^2}{2})'=e^\frac{(lnx)^2}{2}\frac{lnx}{x}$$

So the question that I have is this: Am I allowed to do the following?

$$ye^\frac{(lnx)^2}{2}=\int{e^\frac{(lnx)^2}{2}\frac{lnx}{x}}dx$$

If no, why?

**Edit:** If this is correct, then if I simplify I get:

$$ yx=\int{lnx}dx $$

and by computing the integral I would end up with this:

$$yx= xlnx -x +c \Rightarrow y=lnx -1+c$$

But if it is done otherwise, like this:

$$(ye^\frac{(lnx)^2}{2})'=(e^\frac{(lnx)^2}{2})'  \Rightarrow ye^\frac{(lnx)^2}{2}=e^\frac{(lnx)^2}{2}$$

I get this result:

$$ y= 1 +c *e^{-\frac{(lnx)^2}{2}} $$

which is different from the other result.

Comment: yes, and the right hand side integrates very easy, because the derivative of the exponent sits right behind.

Comment: The thing is that my professor is solving this with a different way, which leads to a different result. He transforms the right hand side as: $(e^\frac{(lnx)^2}{2})'$ and erases the $'$ from both sides.

Comment: Well, we would need to see those computations too then to see where it differs (IF it differs...)

Comment: Everything looks good. Just be sure to be mindful of the initial conditions.

Comment: there is a $x>0$ condition. Would that change something?

Comment: @imranfat I show the computations in my question now.

Comment: Are you saying that $e^{\frac{(\ln x)^2}{2}}=x$?

Answer (score 0):

write your equation in the form
$$\frac{dy}{1-y}=\frac{\log(x)}{x}dx$$